# Are papers corrected by the publisher after acceptance?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I am submitting the camera ready version of a paper for a conference in machine learning. The proceedings will be published by a well known publisher of the area. I have a question:

after the upload of the camera ready version, is the paper edited in some way by the publisher? Assume that I add typos or strange/not existing english words: is the paper going to be published with these errors, or there is someone-not-scientist who corrects the paper?

Comment: It depends, sometimes it's published as is, sometimes not. Email the conference organisers and ask.

Comment: Sometimes the publisher adds new errors.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot speak for that conference, but for all the conferences I happened to participate in my field (in a couple of cases as a member of the organizing committee) for *camera-ready* submissions, there were no corrections after the submission.

Usually, the editor of the proceedings puts together all the submitted papers and adds page numbers, table of contents, list of participants etc. That's it.

Comment: I've had a conference paper that was requested as camera-ready go through some editor (who messed up my references...). Though I agree that normally camera-ready is probably used for what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Some journals will copy-edit papers post-acceptance for typos, clarity, etc. but in my experience if they're asking for "camera-ready" submissions, they're not planning on doing this.

Regardless, you should never *rely* on the journal doing that sort of editing.